# Simulate HTTPS API using Hoverfly

Tags: java, hoverfly

I am trying to simulate HTTPS API in Hoverfly but getting below error

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I tried setting `localHoverflyConfig.disableTlsVerification();` but this also not working.

Application runs inside `Docker Container` and I am importing the certificate inside cacerts inside docker file using `keytool`

Not able to find proper documentation for Java.